# Trying to understand how AngularJS $parse service works

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to understand what angularjs $parse service does. I have read the official documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse but that's not really helping. Searching online did not render any good examples.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$parse takes in a string and returns you a function. Below is a simple example of it in action

http://plnkr.co/edit/nicdbwVL2ZZbljZy2Z9S

Comment: Thanks your example helps .. One question through .. why pass scope to the function call  fn(scope, {})   and why use scope.apply() at the end ?

Comment: The event originated outside of angular so you need let angular and the function know the context.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to explain but could not do a better job than [this post](http://umur.io/advanced-angular-parse/)

"*$parse takes an expression, and returns you a function. When you call the returned function with context as first argument. It will execute the expression with the given context.*"

**In the simplest form**: It's main purpose is for example to access some tags click function with the right context inside a directive without tight coupling so you can execute it (maybe with some extra params).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `$parse` from my POV is to let us evaluate a "property" from a given `$scope`. The result of calling `$parse` is "property", for example:

**my controller**

```
$scope.author.name = "Hello World";
```

somewhere else under the same controller:

```
var property = $parse("author.name");
```

**Property Getter**:  `property($scope);` in this case it is evaluated against the same scope.

**Property Setter**:  `property.assign($scope,'Felipe');` assigns a new value to the author name.

`$scope` give us the context where to evaluate or search for the "property".

I have found them useful when creating **directives** to still maintain the directive decoupled from the controller but still needing to interact with objects present in the controller.